# Get HTML Source Code Despite Of Forwarding

Tags: c#, php, html, web

I'm trying to get HTML source code of a web site.

However with php and file_get_contents() it sent me another source code 
and with cURL I take an 302 found.

```
$c = curl_init($http);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));


$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);

echo $html;
```

I tried download it by C#, but in that way also, it sent me another source code.

How I reach its contents? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

302 is a redirect, try setting curl to follow it:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);`

Comment: I tried. It works now but this source code is also different.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP codes 302 and 301 are forwarders to another page and ideally have no content to be read.

cURL don't follow redirects by default, thats why you are getting the return of the 302 code. You have to set the option to follow the new location automatically on cURL:

```
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```